# Codeigniter pressing logout button and disable the back browser button

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hello guys i am using CodeIgniter Framework, i have a problem within after logout, the session is already destroyed and redirect to login form, and after redirecting to login form, the browser back button can be backed to dashboard but there are errors because of the session was destroyed already. All i want is to disable the back button of the browser or anything that my previous cant be loaded. I have read other posts about this problem and tried their solution but it doesn't work. I have already pasted this code based on what I've read in other post in my constructor.

```
The code that I've seen from the post and posted in my constructor :
 header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        // HTTP/1.0
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        // Date in the past
        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        // always modified
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

here is my logout:

```
 $sess_array = array(
        'username' => ''
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('auth', 'refresh');
```

here is from my dashboard :

```
    <li>                                 
<a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout') ?>"><i3 class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i3> Logout</a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tired to implement this option but it doesn't works well. So i implement new logic on this.

> Simply check is session is set in every main methods. Below code help you

**In logout(define in controller)**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ob_start(); # add this
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->load->driver('cache');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->cache->clean();
    ob_clean();
    redirect('home'); # Login form or some other page         
}
```

**In dashboard(Function)**

```
public function home()
{
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if($logged_in != TRUE || empty($logged_in))
    {
        #user not logged in
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Session has Expired');
        redirect('user_logging'); # Login view
    }
    else
    {
        #user Logged in
        $this->load->view("viewname",$data);
    }
}
```

**In Login(function)**

```
$session = array(
    'username'  => $name,
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

Comment: hello sir, how can i manipulate this code
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

to satisfy the if condition about logged_in = TRUE

Comment: what is your session fields ??

Comment: $session_data = array (
                'user_email' => $res[0]->user_email,
                'user_id' => $res[0]->user_id,
                'usertype_name' => $res[0]->usertype_name,
                'user_fname' => $res[0]->user_fname,
                'user_mname' => $res[0]->user_mname,
                'user_lname' => $res[0]->user_lname
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

Comment: @AbdullaNilam can you explain why you are loading the cache driver? curious

Comment: @Alex that for this Jc John's requirement. He was used cache when i check his code. clear now?

Comment: i have one doubt, when v are logged in to our account it should stay on the same page it should not go back even tough the user press back key, im trying it wrok on this but im unable to do please can u guys suggest me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493658/error-while-login-and-logout-using-codeigniter/51493968?noredirect=1#comment89958527_51493968  please can u guys go through this link

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem: If going back after logout leads to a page full of errors, going to that page directly would cause the same problem.

This should never occur, instead when someone tries to open a page that should not be opened when not logged-in, the visitor should be directed to the login page.

Apart from that you should not mess with the user's browser experience. So even you could, you should not disable the back-button. And even if you could, it could probably easily be circumvented by disabling javascript (for example...).

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. My code works good, it provide errors after logout because the session is already destroyed. How can i solve this sir ?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, set the userdata session value when you successfully log in to the admin panel use this line after all the validation you have done on login from

$this->session->set_userdata('admin_id',$admin_id);

you can just do 1 thing to avoid direct login of ant of the pages of your user panel or admin panel, just make a constructor in your admin controller like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(! $this->session->userdata('admin_id')){
        return redirect('login_controller');//your login controller which have login page as view in index function//
    }
}
```

and use the logout function like this:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('admin_id');
    return redirect('login_controller');
}
```

by this way, after you log out from the admin panel and try to use back button or try to use the direct calling of any of the admin panel page or function it won't open,it works for me and still using this code in user and admin panel making

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

Your login function

```
function login() {

     $query = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password);

     foreach ($query as $row) {
          $username = $row->username;
     }

     $session_array = array(
          'username' => $username,
          'logged_in' => TRUE
     );

     $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_array);
}
```

Your logout function

```
public function logout() {

    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
```

And in the dashboard or home controller

```
function index() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') !== FALSE && ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['login_type'] == "" ))
    {
         // Your codes 
    } else {
       redirect('login/logout');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the construct method at the beginning of your admin controller, inside construct add the condition it will work in every function as long as the controller is admin,

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(! $this->session->userdata('admin_id')){
        return redirect('login_controller');//your login controller which have login page as view in index function//
    }
} 


but as you move on deep into your web application and browse through several controllers and methods, you will encounter "page not found page" if you log out somewhere in the middle of the page with a controller other than admin,

To solve this problem add the construct method like below code in all the controllers construct at the beginning and then you will be able to logout from anywhere with session destroy,



public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(! $this->session->userdata('admin_id')){
        return redirect('login_controller');//your login controller which have login page as view in index function//
    }
}
```