# View the Dashboard after logout with browser back button

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, logout

I m new to codeigniter framework. I know this question has been asked many times. I have done R & D but i m unable to get it working. I m stuck at the moment. I m using the codeigniter framework 2.2.2. I have used the session for login as following:

Login Controller

```
public function loginMe()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[32]|');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->login_model->loginMe($username, $password);

        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($result as $res)
            {
                $sessionArray = array('userId'=>$res->userId,
                                        'role'=>$res->roleId,
                                        'roleText'=>$res->role,
                                        'name'=>$res->name,
                                        'isLoggedIn' => TRUE
                                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);

                redirect('/dashboard');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username or password mismatch');

            redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

When the user is logout i m calling the logout function in user controller:

User Controller Logout function:

```
function logout() {

    $this->session->sess_destroy ();
     ob_clean();
    redirect ('login');
}
```

Up to this everything is working fine. I can logout to login page but when i click on the browser back button i can see the dashboard. This shouldnt be done. 
My User controller constructor is checking the session or isloggedin().

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ob_start();
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $this->isLoggedIn();   
}
function isLoggedIn() {
    $isLoggedIn = $this->session->userdata ( 'isLoggedIn' );

if (! isset ( $isLoggedIn ) || $isLoggedIn != TRUE || empty($isLoggedIn)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Session has Expired');
        redirect ( 'login' );
    } else {
        $this->role = $this->session->userdata ( 'role' );
        $this->vendorId = $this->session->userdata ( 'userId' );
        $this->name = $this->session->userdata ( 'name' );
        $this->roleText = $this->session->userdata ( 'roleText' );
        $this->lastLogin = $this->session->userdata ( 'lastLogin' );

        $this->global ['name'] = $this->name;
        $this->global ['role'] = $this->role;
        $this->global ['role_text'] = $this->roleText;
        $this->global ['last_login'] = $this->lastLogin;
    }
}
```

I have done everything i can but its not working. I have followed this [Codeigniter pressing logout button and disable the back browser button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426200/codeigniter-pressing-logout-button-and-disable-the-back-browser-button). But it couldn't solve my problem. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CI 2's session is a mess, any reason you can't upgrade?

Comment: @Alex I m using some one's template. So i want to keep stick to it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right a function to clear cache and call it in the constructor.

```
function clear_cache()
{
   $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to put cache-control headers, like this:

```
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: I was doing this before but it wasnt working as i didnt know where to put it exact. Thanks for your comment @EugeneR