# Error: while login and logout using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The login and logout is working fine but, after getting logout from the page im still able to access that page, for example in url if i use as codeigniter_try/index.php/Home/backend its displaying the page which should not happen, i mean to say it should display only when i loggedin with the username and password. what issue im facing here can any one guide me ?

This is my Controller.php

```
//-------this is Login method --------
public function login()
{
    if($this->input->post('login'))
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $query=$this->db->query("select * from login where username='".$username."' and password='$password'");
        $row = $query->num_rows();
        if($row)
        {
            $newdata=array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'is_logged_in'=>TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            redirect('Home/Backend');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error']="<h3 style='color:red'>Invalid login details</h3>";
        }   
    }

    $this->load->view('login',@$data);      
}

//---------this is Logout method --------
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('Home/login');
}

//-------Backend page---------

     public function Backend()
   {
     $this->load->view('backend');
     }
```

Comment: don't try and reinvent the wheel. use ion_auth. also `md5` is horribly insecure, even php says so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*your `logout` method should be like this :*

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('Home/login');
}
```

*Your `Backend` should be like this : you have to check it in all controllers*

```
public function Backend()
{ 
   if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) redirect('Home/login'); 
   $this->load->view('backend'); 
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session

Comment: It's not working sir

Comment: you have to check it in your home controller whether it has session `is_logged_in` or not

Comment: Sir please check my updated answer

Comment: hope this gives u some idea : `public function Backend()
{
    if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) redirect('Home/login');
    $this->load->view('backend');
}`

Comment: sir this is working but when i login na then it should say on the same page even tough  try to go back it should not go. i tried with this but its nit working

Comment: there must be something wrong with logic , keep it simple, if login then check for session, if found go to home otherwise go to login, and this should be all in your controllers

Comment: Sir I got it what u said to do in ur pervious comment I tried in the login comment and it worked,  thank you sir. For suggestion. And please the comment which you did please paste it on the answer section so that I can accept it

Comment: ok updated my answer, pls check it as accepted if helps you

Answer (score 1):

unset_userdata() can be used to remove it, by passing the session key.

so, logout function will be change like this.

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('password');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');

/*
Or

    $array_items = array('username' , 'password' , 'is_logged_in');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
*/

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('Home/login');
}
```

Comment: It's not working sir

Comment: I think there is a problem in places that has nothing to do with calling unset_userdata and sess_destroy. We need to look at the logic of pages that process access through session data.